# LM35 decreases when near heat

Tags: arduino

My LM35 connected to arduino decreases temperature value in celsius when near heat and increases value when far from heat. Could any one help or know why it's working other way round.

```
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    //Start the serial connection with the computer
    //to view the result open the serial monitor 
    // 9600 is the “baud rate”, or communications speed.
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    delay(2000);
    float tempValue = analogRead(A2);
    // converting that reading to voltage
    float tempVoltage = (tempValue/1024.0)*5.0;
    float tempDegrees = (tempVoltage - 0.5) * 100.0 ;  
    //Multiplying tempDegrees by -1 to make it positive
    tempDegrees =(tempDegrees * -1);
    Serial.println("............................................");
    Serial.println("Degrees");
    Serial.println(tempDegrees);
    delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: swap your Vcc and Gnd connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just randomly came accross your question. and it has been 6 years since I touched an LM35 :d 
but I think you have a problem in that -0.5  thing. I did not really get that! 
LM35's function as far as I remember was :
T = V/ 10mV

you might want to check the datasheet but I'm pretty positive this is the equation. when you get the voltage from ADC you have to put it in this equation and get the result. 
be careful : you have to also attribute for the temperature error as well as ADC noise if temperature precision is important for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a 5 volts power supply to your arduino:

5 Volts in the Arduino are directly converted to 1023 in the output of the ADC

**ADC_Outpput  *  5000 / 1024**, where 5000 is coming from 5volts as millivolts, 1024 is the 10 bist resolution

[LM35](http://www.ti.com/product/LM35) resolution is linearly generated with a rate of   + 10-mV/°C

so the **analogVolt = ADC_Outpput  *  5000 / 1024**

**FinalTemperature = (analogVolt  - 500) / 10**